# Typo3 Typoscript GIFBUILDER - The best way to generate a simple grayscale image

Tags: image, typo3, typoscript, grayscale

Can anyone show how to set a typoscript to simply generate grayscale image?

I'm searching for the best way regardless of the imagemagick version.

Is there a simplest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert an existing image to greyscale with TypoScript, an easy solution is as following.

```
10 = IMAGE
10 {
  file = path/to/image.jpg
  file.width = 100
  file.height = 100
  file.params = -type Grayscale
}
```

If you want to use GIFBUILDER for the task, you can use the following TypoScript and add additional TypoScript (e.g. mask, text) to the IMAGE object inside the GIFBUILDER.

```
10 = IMAGE
10 {
  file = GIFBUILDER
  file {
    XY = 100,100
    format = jpg
    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
      file = path/to/image.jpg
      file.width = 100
      file.height = 100
      file.params = -type Grayscale
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's it. Simple solution. I was looking for the one with GIFFBUILDER.
Thanks @derhansen.